# Xcode can't click on error in issue navigator

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm getting this error:

[image: Xcode Error]

Usually If I'm unsure why I'm getting this error I click on it to see more information about it. However when I click it nothing happens.

Why can't I click it anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's linker error. Linker can't find some symbol so it can't show where exactly error appears. In fact linker knows nothing about your code. If you don't add or remove libraries in your project try to clean project or remove derived data, it will force to recompile a whole project.

Answer (score 0):

It might also help to right click on the error and select "Reveal in Log".

Answer (score 0):

sometimes this error can't find or gets opened  on just a normal double click..but on right click and selecting **Reveal in log** will definitely help you